# data not displaying in table in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

i have created vue file to display data in frontend. but i'm unable to print 2 tables on same page at same time. only table 2 is displaying data , in first table it shows data for 2 seconds and than disappears. what i'm doing wrong? please help. i am super new in vuejs and have not much knowledge.

here is my index.vue file,

**Table 1**

```
            <tbody>
              <tr
              v-show="items && items.length"
              v-for="(data, i) in items"
              :key="i">
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
             </tr>
```

and this is function code,

```
async fetchData1() {
  this.$store.state.operations.loading = true;
  let currentPage = this.pagination ? this.pagination.current_page : 1;
  await this.$store.dispatch("operations/fetchData", {
    path: "/api/calldata?page=",
    currentPage: currentPage + "&perPage=" + this.perPage,
  });
```

**table 2**

```
<tbody>
              <tr
              v-show="items && items.length"
              v-for="(data, i) in items"
              :key="i">
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
             </tr>
```

and here is the function for table 2

```
async fetchData2() {
  this.Loading2 = true
  let currentPage = this.Pagination2 ? this.Pagination2.current_page : 1;
   await this.$store.dispatch("operations/fetchData", {
    path: "/api/datacall/data2?page=",
    currentPage: currentPage + "&perPage=" + this.perPage,
  });
  this.Loading2 = false;
```

and this are the controller functions

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  return DataResource::collection(Datamodl::with('user')->where('type',1)->latest()->paginate($request->perPage));
}

public function index2(Request $request)
{
  return DataResource::collection(Datamodl::with('user')->where('type',0)->latest()->paginate($request->perPage));
}
```

And Route ,

```
Route::get('/calldata/data2', [DataController::class, 'index2']);
Route::apiResource('calldata', DataController::class);
```

Comment: both are sharing same `items` property. Hence, it is updating latest one and showing the second table.

Comment: How can i have 2 item veritable ? Item is in mapper. And when i try to add new variable in mapper , it's not working. How can i have 2 different variables ?

Comment: you can create two local component variables (table1Items & table2Items) in data object and then assign the api response in those variables and then use in the HTML template.

Comment: I have tried that already.. but in that case only processing is happening.. and it's keep processing. Nothing happens after. @RohìtJíndal

Comment: I added an answer. Hope that will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Observation :*** You are updating same variable which is `items` for both the tables. Hence, it is overriding the latest `items` with the old `items` array.

***Solution :*** Here is the implementation as per my comment.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    table1Items: null,
    table2Items: null
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData1();
    this.fetchData2();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData1() {
        this.table1Items = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'table 1 alpha'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'table 1 beta'
      }]
    },
    fetchData2() {
        this.table2Items = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'table 2 alpha'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'table 2 beta'
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-show="table1Items" v-for="(data, i) in table1Items" :key="i">
        <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-show="table2Items" v-for="(data, i) in table2Items" :key="i">
        <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using same property which is items for both. so second request will changed first items. so in both table same data will visible. you have to store in different state property for different data rendering.

**solution** :

1. make another action fetchData2.
2. call another mutation setItems2.  add state propery  **item2: []**. and setItems2 value from this mutation.
3. render second table like this.

   ```
        <tr
          v-show="items2.length"
          v-for="(data, i) in items2"
          :key="i">
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
         </tr>
   ```

**For code quailty:**

1. give proper and related variable name . don't use items1 and items2 like that.
2. never used v-if/v-show and v-for in same element.[for more info](https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-essential.html#avoid-v-if-with-v-for)

   **use template first in this senerio.**
3. use the item's unique id instead of the index in the key.
4. if you take the **items default value as [], instead of null**, then you only required to check **items.length** instead of **items && items.length**. so **always use list default value []**
5. if both requests are not dependent on each other then you should use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for fetching data concurrently. which saved tremendous time and also in this case you don't require two loading property.